# Insert space after every character of a text string

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to create a formula that takes a text string of unknown length and returns it after inserting a space between every character.

For example, if `A1="FOO"` then the formula should return `"F O O"`.

I can successfully return my example above with the following formula, but it's long and is hard-coded for 3 character strings:

```
=MID(A1,1,1)& " "&
 MID(A1,2,1)& " "&
 MID(A1,3,1)
```

Is there a more compact method that works with strings of any length?

Comment: A [chat discussion regarding this question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148670/discussion-on-question-by-patrick-hennessey-insert-space-after-every-character-o) has been created.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem with the following formula:

```
 =TRIM(
    REGEXREPLACE(
      A1, "(.)", "$1 "))
```

---

Credit to [@Erik Tyler](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/197265/erik-tyler) for suggesting the TRIM function which provided a much shorter approach to remove trailing spaces.

Comment: Even though the question is self-answered, you can still accept it and are encouraged to do so **after 48 hours** if it is the best solution.  You can always change your mind later if a better solution comes along.

Comment: Since we seem to share an interest in shortening our code, you can remove an additional 2 characters by removing the parentheses from the regex and changing the `$1` to `$0`. So,  your formula would become: `=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1, ".", "$0 "))`